# Python 3.+, Scipy Stats Mode function gives Type Error unorderable types: str() > float()

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, anaconda, kaggle

I am trying to solve kaggle titanic disaster problem, specifically using mode/ mean/ median to input missing values. Here is a peak at my data set

```
   Parch            Ticket     Fare Cabin Embarked  
0      0         A/5 21171   7.2500   NaN        S  
1      0          PC 17599  71.2833   C85        C  
2      0  STON/O2. 3101282   7.9250   NaN        S  
3      0            113803  53.1000  C123        S  
4      0            373450   8.0500   NaN        S
```

I am trying to get the mode of 'Embarked' Column and type 'Object'. I am using python3. Here is the code snippet:

```
modeEmbarked = mode(df.Embarked)
```

Here is the error snippet:

```
<ipython-input-39-1b4237d65022> in clean(df)
     18 
     19     # Cleaning Embarked column
---> 20     modeEmbarked = mode(df.Embarked)
     21 #     print(mode(df.Embarked))
     22 #     le_embarked = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

/home/singhaniya/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py in mode(a, axis)
    635     return np.array([]), np.array([])
    636 
--> 637     scores = np.unique(np.ravel(a))       # get ALL unique values
    638     testshape = list(a.shape)
    639     testshape[axis] = 1

/home/singhaniya/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py in unique(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    196         aux = ar[perm]
    197     else:
--> 198         ar.sort()
    199         aux = ar
    200     flag = np.concatenate(([True], aux[1:] != aux[:-1]))

TypeError: unorderable types: str() > float()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
modeEmbarked = mode(df.Embarked.dropna())
```

using this insetead of

```
modeEmbarked = mode(df.Embarked)
```

solves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have mixed types in `df.Embarked`. Make sure all items are the same type (or types that can be compared).

Or use `Series.mode()`, which can handle mixed types.

Comment: yes! there are NAN values, but the tutorial I am working with does not do anything extra and produce the same result!
However I can do the same if I run it with dropna()

Comment: @AnkitSinghaniya Whatever your tutorial says, `scipy.stats.mode()` is unable to compute modes of arrays of mixed types, at least the version of scipy installed in my computer. The pandas version of `mode()` can do it though, see my edit.

Comment: you were right in pointing out about mixed values. I think NAN values were the problem.